# ios shareApplication rootviewcontroller.frame flip-flops on Y axis

Tags: ios, uiapplication, cgrect, keywindow

I have an iPad application where I'm moving the application's frame "up" every time the *soft* keyboard is shown.

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, 1024, 768);
```

The *clincher* is that on some devices this goes the **correct** way, but on other's it goes the **opposite** direction than I want it to. It doesn't seem to be hardware specific or even software specific. I have tried it on 4 iPads (two ipad1, two ipad3 and one ipad2) all with ios 5.1 (9B176). Is there a way to know if this is going to happen on a device so that I can combat this with logic?

Also, It seems that devices that are going to do this do it and stay that way as well (and vice-versa). Once it happens, it always happens or not regardless of software update, device restart, app removal, or IPA vs ran-from-xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the view's frame - but the frame coordinates need to be relative to the view's superview (in this case the keyWindow), not itself.
Since the window is never rotated, your frame coordinates will be interpreted differently, depending on the device's current orientation.

You could do the following to convert your frame coordinates to ones suitable for the keyWindow:

```
CGRect newFrame = [self.view convertRect:CGRectMake(0, 150, 1024, 768) toView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: haha, this is it! I'm sending IPAs to my friend and I he must hold his iPad differently than I do. Oh man, so simple but my mind was boxed into one way of thinking. Thanks for your help!